# Using 2 WCF interfaces in the same svc file

Tags: wcf, web-config, svc

We are trying to communicate with an external WCF service.

The WCF services are exposed via svc files. It appears that there are 2 interfaces exposed via the same svc file.

How can we configure this in the web.config file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a single class that implements 2 WCF service contracts. In your web.config, you configure an endpoint for each service contract, but under the same `<service>` node. I've only done this when self-hosting WCF services, not in IIS, but I think if you specify a value for `address` in your endpoint configuration, it will make it relative to the location of the .svc file:

```
<service name="YourServiceLibrary.YourServiceClass">
  <endpoint address="Service1"
    contract="YourServiceLibrary.IService1"
    ...
     />
  <endpoint address="Service2"
    contract="YourServiceLibrary.IService2"
    ...
     />
</service>
```

You would then setup your client proxies for each service contract to point to `http://YourServer/YourServicePath/YourServiceClass.svc/Service1` and `http://YourServer/YourServicePath/YourServiceClass.svc/Service2`